# Multiple Loops on category.php with pagination on last loop

Tags: categories, wp-query, loop, pagination

I'm trying to achieve what should be fairly simple but I've hit a brick wall when trying to paginate the last of three loops on the category.php template. I've read just about everything I can find on this subject and can't seem to get a functioning result.

I'm using WP_QUERY on all three loop which is where the problem starts, I've tried all conventional ways of solving this problem.

This is what I want to achieve:

```
<-- Feature loop of 2 posts -->

--HTML--

<-- Loop 6 posts -->

--HTML--

<-- Loop another 6 posts and paginate this loop -->
```

Here is my basic code:

```
<?php
    $category = get_queried_object();
?>

<?php   
    $args = array( 
    'category__and' => array(158, $category->term_id),
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'tag__not_in' => 1596
    );  
$feature = new WP_Query( $args ); while( $feature->have_posts() ) : $feature->the_post(); ?>

    <!-- LOOP CONTENTS -->

<?php $removeDuplicates[] = get_the_ID();?>
<?php endwhile; ?>



<!-- SECOND LOOP STARTS -->


<div class="array grid-block">
    <?php

    $argpost1 = array(
        'cat' => $category->term_id,
        'tag__not_in' => 1596,
        'posts_per_page' => 8
    );

    $posts = new WP_Query( $argpost1 ); while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
    <?php if(array_search(get_the_ID(),$removeDuplicates) === false) { ?>

    <!-- LOOP CONTENTS -->

    <?php $removeDuplicates[] = get_the_ID();?>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>


<!-- THIRD LOOP STARTS -->


<div class="array-load grid-block">
    <?php
    $page = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

    $argpost2 = array(
        'cat' => $category->term_id,
        'tag__not_in' => 1596,
        'posts_per_page' =>  6,
        'page' =>  $page
    );                  
    $posts1 = new WP_Query( $argpost2 ); while( $posts1->have_posts() ) : $posts1->the_post(); ?>
    <?php if(array_search(get_the_ID(),$removeDuplicates) === false) { ?>

    <!-- LOOP CONTENTS -->

    <?php $removeDuplicates[] = get_the_ID();?>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>

<nav id="paging">
    <?php next_posts_link( 'More Articles' ); wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi Adam, Welcome to WPSE. Just one request, do not use third party services to host your code. Add it directly to your question. First of all, your question should be a reference for future users, so if the paste is ever removed, your question will be meaningless. Also, it is really really frustrating switching between a couple of screens to read one post. Please keep that in mind. :-) Thank you

Comment: Basically, your paginated loop should be the main query, that's what the number of available pages is based on. Use pre_get_posts to alter that query rather than create a new one in the template

Comment: Pieter, I do apologise. Thank you for editing for me, I will make sure I enter the code directly next time.

Comment: Milo, thank you. I will read up on pre_get_posts and make adjustments.

Comment: review http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link#Usage_when_querying_the_loop_with_WP_Query

Comment: Sorry to sound stupid, I've read the section on pre_get_posts and can't see how I can implement it when I have three queries?